# how to implement BST inorder traversal?

Tags: search, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal, inorder

Actually what I want to know is not how to implement the in-order traversal algorithm for a BST but to implement it only using insertion, deletion and pre-order traversal algorithms for a BST.
You can assume that you are given the implementations for standard BST algorithms for insertion, deletion and pre-order traversal.

Comment: Have you searched a bit around ?? Look at this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... Lets say we have + at root and 1 at left node and 2 at right node. The pre-order will be `+ 1 2` and in order will be `1 + 2`.. the difference is that 1st and 2nd have been swapped , so if you have insertion and deletion you can recursively swap each root node value with its left node value and then using pre-order traverse the tree which will return will cause a  inorder traversal.

I am not sure if this is the way to go, but I hope it does help.

Comment: Ankur, seems you have got something wrong somewhere. We can delete and insert an element but it doesn't swap the two elements since all the insertion and deletion operations will take place that they secure the Binary search property.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution. :)

we have pre-order traversal, insertion and deletion methods.

Assume that we are given a BST.

what we do is, we provide the pre-order traversal method with the given BST. since pre-order traversal always go to the parent node first, we delete and insert each root(because the root is the first parent we meet) node recursively until the left sub tree of the root is null.

now you start deleting the root until there's no nodes left.Put those deleted nodes in an array or wherever you want. You will get the sorted set of nodes. (i.e. the nodes will be deleted in a sorted order.the smallest first and so on...)